How to prevent page overflow while allowing internal component overflow in React with Tailwind CSS?
I'm building a React application with Tailwind CSS and I'm facing an issue with overflow handling. I want to prevent the main page from scrolling while still allowing internal components, such as tables, to handle their own overflow (i.e., scrolling within the component).
Here's a simplified version of my setup:
Layout Component
import Sidebar from './Sidebar';
import { Outlet } from 'react-router-dom';

const Layout = () => {
  return (
    <div className='flex bg-foreground dark:bg-[#969696] max-h-screen overflow-hidden'>
      <Sidebar />
      <div className='flex flex-col flex-1 overflow-hidden'>
        <div className='border-muted-foreground/20 flex-1 p-3.5 overflow-hidden max-h-screen'>
          <Outlet />
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Layout;


ProgramOverviewPage Component
import BreadCrumb from '@/components/BreadCrumb';
import DataTable from '@/components/DataGrid/DataTable';

const ProgramOverviewPage = () => {
  return (
    <div className='flex flex-col gap-4 h-full'>
      <div className=''>
        <BreadCrumb page='T_Program_Overview' />
      </div>
      <div className='flex-1 p-6 overflow-hidden bg-background rounded-xl'>
        <DataTable />
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default ProgramOverviewPage;


DataTable Component
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { Table, TableBody, TableCell, TableHead, TableHeader, TableRow } from '@/components/ui/table';
import { Collapsible, CollapsibleContent, CollapsibleTrigger } from '@/components/ui/collapsible';
import { ChevronsUpDown, MoreHorizontal } from 'lucide-react';
import ProgramData from './ProgramData';
import { Button } from '@/components/ui/button';
import { Input } from '@/components/ui/input';
import { DropdownMenu, DropdownMenuContent, DropdownMenuItem, DropdownMenuLabel, DropdownMenuSeparator, DropdownMenuTrigger } from '@/components/ui/dropdown-menu';
import { useFetchParams } from '@/api/querys';
import Pagination from '@/utils/Pagination';
import { ChevronRight, ChevronLeft } from 'lucide-react';
import FilterDialog from './FilterDialog';
import AddEditProgram from './AddEditProgram';
import { useTranslation } from 'react-i18next';
import { getRowClassName } from '@/utils/getRowClassName';

const PAGE_SIZE = 5;

function DataTable() {
  const { t } = useTranslation();
  const { data } = useFetchParams();
  const [currentPage, setCurrentPage] = useState(1);
  const [searchQuery, setSearchQuery] = useState('');
  const [filteredData, setFilteredData] = useState([]);
  const [filters, setFilters] = useState({});
  const [activeFilterCount, setActiveFilterCount] = useState(0);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (data) {
      setFilteredData(data);
    }
  }, [data]);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (data) {
      const filtered = data
        .filter((item) => {
          if (!searchQuery) return true;
          return Object.values(item).some((value) => value?.toString().toLowerCase().includes(searchQuery.toLowerCase()));
        })
        .filter((item) => {
          return Object.keys(filters).every((key) => {
            const filterValues = filters[key] || [];
            if (filterValues.length === 0 || filterValues.includes('Alle')) return true;
            return filterValues.includes(item[key]?.toString() || '');
          });
        });

      setFilteredData(filtered);
      setActiveFilterCount(Object.values(filters).reduce((acc, cur) => acc + cur.length, 0));
    }
  }, [searchQuery, filters, data]);

  if (!data) return <div>Loading...</div>;

  const filteredColumns = data.length > 0 ? Object.keys(data[0]).filter((key) => key !== 'ID') : [];
  const totalPages = Math.ceil(filteredData.length / PAGE_SIZE);
  const paginatedData = filteredData.slice((currentPage - 1) * PAGE_SIZE, currentPage * PAGE_SIZE);

  const handlePreviousPage = () => setCurrentPage((prevPage) => Math.max(prevPage - 1, 1));
  const handleNextPage = () => setCurrentPage((prevPage) => Math.min(prevPage + 1, totalPages));
  const handleSearchQueryChange = (event) => setSearchQuery(event.target.value);
  const handleFilterChange = (column, values) => setFilters((prevFilters) => ({ ...prevFilters, [column]: values }));
  const handleAddProgram = (newProgram) => setFilteredData((prevData) => [...prevData, newProgram]);

  return (
    <div className='w-full h-full flex flex-col'>
      <div className='py-4 px-1 flex items-center gap-4 justify-between'>
        <div className='flex gap-3'>
          <div className='border-gray-300 rounded-md border-2 flex focus-visible:ring-offset-0 focus-visible:ring-0'>
            <Input placeholder={t('T_Search')} value={searchQuery} onChange={handleSearchQueryChange} className='max-w-sm focus-visible:ring-offset-0 focus-visible:ring-0' />
          </div>
          <FilterDialog columns={filteredColumns} data={data} onFilterChange={handleFilterChange} activeFilterCount={activeFilterCount} />
        </div>
        <AddEditProgram onAddProgram={handleAddProgram} />
      </div>
      <div className='rounded-xl border overflow-auto flex-1'>
        <Table>
          <TableHeader className='w-full text-secondary bg-gray-200 dark:bg-popover'>
            <TableRow>
              <TableHead className='sr-only'>{t('T_Actions')}</TableHead>
              {filteredColumns.map((column) => <TableHead key={column}>{column}</TableHead>)}
              <TableHead>{t('T_Actions')}</TableHead>
            </TableRow>
          </TableHeader>
          <TableBody>
            {paginatedData.map((item, index) => (
              <Collapsible key={index} asChild>
                <>
                  <TableRow className={getRowClassName(index)}>
                    <TableCell className='py-0'>
                      <CollapsibleTrigger className=''>
                        <ChevronsUpDown className='text-secondary-foreground' />
                      </CollapsibleTrigger>
                    </TableCell>
                    {filteredColumns.map((column) => (
                      <TableCell key={`${item.ProgramID}-${column}`} className='text-[1.1rem]'>{item[column] ?? 'N/A'}</TableCell>
                    ))}
                    <TableCell className='py-0'>
                      <DropdownMenu>
                        <DropdownMenuTrigger asChild>
                          <Button variant='ghost' className='h-8 w-8 p-0'>
                            <span className='sr-only'>{t('T_Actions')}</span>
                            <MoreHorizontal className='h-4 w-4' />
                          </Button>
                        </DropdownMenuTrigger>
                        <DropdownMenuContent align='end'>
                          <DropdownMenuLabel>{t('T_Actions')}</DropdownMenuLabel>
                          <DropdownMenuItem>{t('T_Edit')}</DropdownMenuItem>
                          <DropdownMenuSeparator />
                          <DropdownMenuItem>{t('T_Delete')}</DropdownMenuItem>
                        </DropdownMenuContent>
                      </DropdownMenu>
                    </TableCell>
                  </TableRow>
                  <TableRow>
                    <CollapsibleContent asChild>
                      <TableCell colSpan={filteredColumns.length + 2} className='bg-popover'>
                        <ProgramData programId={item.ProgramID.toString()} />
                      </TableCell>
                    </CollapsibleContent>
                  </TableRow>
                </>
              </Collapsible>
            ))}
            {paginatedData.length === 0 && (
              <TableRow>
                <TableCell colSpan={filteredColumns.length + 2} className='h-24 text-center'>{t('T_No_Results')}</TableCell>
              </TableRow>
            )}
          </TableBody>
        </Table>
      </div>
      <div className='flex items-center justify-between space-x-2 py-4'>
        <div className='flex items-center space-x-2'>
          <Button variant='link' size='sm' onClick={handlePreviousPage} disabled={currentPage === 1}>
            <ChevronLeft className='dark:text-muted-foreground' />
          </Button>
          <Pagination totalPages={totalPages} currentPage={currentPage} setCurrentPage={setCurrentPage} />
          <Button variant='link' size='sm' onClick={handleNextPage} disabled={currentPage === totalPages}>
            <ChevronRight className='dark:text-muted-foreground' />
          </Button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default DataTable;

The main issue is that I want to prevent the main page from scrolling, but still allow the DataTable component to scroll internally (both horizontally and vertically if needed).
What I've Tried:
Setting overflow-hidden on the main layout to prevent page scrolling.
Setting overflow-auto on the DataTable component to handle its own scrolling.
Using max-h-screen, h-full, and similar height utilities to ensure proper sizing and overflow handling.
Despite these attempts, the main page still scrolls, and the internal scrolling in the DataTable component doesn't work as intended.

You can achieve that by adding fixed height & overflow to internal component. Full height will just cover whole height with respect to parent.
